# Sort ruby middleman array into 3 columns, content in placed in order to display LTR

Tags: ruby, middleman

I am using middleman and have a specific structure that I want my articles to fall into:

```
.row>
  .col-1>article 1, article 4...
  .col-2>article 2, article 5...
  .col-3>article 3, article 6...
```

The goal is that the articles read left-to-right, however are stacked in their columns so there is now additional row class that is needed. I have these articles enclosed in a visual card, and want to stack them which is why I have this strange problem to solve.

My question is what is the cleanest ruby way to sort the array into this format? The goal is to use it in a structure like this and be able to account for any number of columns, n.

```
.row
  - page_articles.someProcess(n).each_split(n) do | col |
    .column-class
      - col.each do | art |
         ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verbatim from `group_by` doc:

```
(1..6).group_by{ |i| i%3 }
    #=> {0=>[3, 6], 1=>[1, 4], 2=>[2, 5]}
```

specifically, use the flatten values

```
page_articles.group_by.with_index{ |a,i| i%3 }.values.flatten(1)
```

Comment: great solution. I arrived at this as the sequence will be off if the array isn't exactly divisible by 3 `page_articles.group_by.with_index{ |a,i| i % 3 }.values.each`